# Innergie 60C USB-C Adapter (charger) creates lag and kernel complains

Tags: 18.04, dell, usb-c, charging

I have this tiny 60W USB-C charger from Innergie and it does charge my Dell XPS 13 DE notebook with Ubuntu 18.04 on it. The problem is that it creates a lag every now and then so I fired up `dmesg -w` and found this:

```
[ 4859.631236] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 52 using xhci_hcd
[ 4859.760583] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4859.995736] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4860.103361] debugfs: Directory '38' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 4860.231297] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 53 using xhci_hcd
[ 4860.360038] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4860.595549] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4860.703295] usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
[ 4861.355373] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 54 using xhci_hcd
[ 4861.355533] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4861.355567] debugfs: Directory '40' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 4861.563574] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4861.563613] debugfs: Directory '41' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 4861.771411] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 54, error -71
[ 4861.903434] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 55 using xhci_hcd
[ 4861.903607] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4862.111609] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4862.319441] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 55, error -71
[ 4862.319548] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 5010.246513] debugfs: Directory '45' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5010.377007] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 56 using xhci_hcd
[ 5010.505040] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5010.749165] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5010.857216] debugfs: Directory '46' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5010.985013] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 57 using xhci_hcd
[ 5011.113171] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5011.357166] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5011.465141] usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
[ 5012.121100] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 58 using xhci_hcd
[ 5012.121285] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5012.121391] debugfs: Directory '48' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5012.329212] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5012.329264] debugfs: Directory '49' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5012.537116] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 58, error -71
[ 5012.665118] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 59 using xhci_hcd
[ 5012.665278] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5012.873417] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5013.081194] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 59, error -71
[ 5013.081287] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 5072.594950] debugfs: Directory '53' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5072.721454] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 60 using xhci_hcd
[ 5072.853655] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5073.089658] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5073.197748] debugfs: Directory '54' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5073.329482] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 61 using xhci_hcd
[ 5073.457680] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5073.697611] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5073.805592] usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
[ 5074.457622] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 62 using xhci_hcd
[ 5074.457847] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5074.458001] debugfs: Directory '56' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5074.665837] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5074.665901] debugfs: Directory '57' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5074.873674] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 62, error -71
[ 5075.001631] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 63 using xhci_hcd
[ 5075.001805] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5075.209774] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5075.417680] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 63, error -71
[ 5075.417729] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 5084.059109] debugfs: Directory '61' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5084.186281] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 64 using xhci_hcd
[ 5084.314323] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5084.550424] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5084.658520] debugfs: Directory '62' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5084.786383] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 65 using xhci_hcd
[ 5084.914382] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5085.150457] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5085.258432] usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
[ 5085.910475] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 66 using xhci_hcd
[ 5085.910676] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5085.910718] debugfs: Directory '64' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5086.118689] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5086.118733] debugfs: Directory '02' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5086.326507] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 66, error -71
[ 5086.454503] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 67 using xhci_hcd
[ 5086.454694] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5086.454738] debugfs: Directory '04' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5086.662707] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5086.662751] debugfs: Directory '05' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5086.870545] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 67, error -71
[ 5086.870627] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 5109.117548] debugfs: Directory '06' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5109.244185] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 68 using xhci_hcd
[ 5109.372329] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5109.608171] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5109.716305] debugfs: Directory '07' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5109.844224] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 69 using xhci_hcd
[ 5109.972201] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5110.208293] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5110.316343] usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
[ 5110.640262] debugfs: Directory '08' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5110.984278] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 70 using xhci_hcd
[ 5110.984495] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5110.984655] debugfs: Directory '09' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5111.192595] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5111.192783] debugfs: Directory '11' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5111.400305] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 70, error -71
[ 5111.528369] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 71 using xhci_hcd
[ 5111.528590] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5111.528734] debugfs: Directory '13' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5111.736633] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5111.736790] debugfs: Directory '14' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5111.944408] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 71, error -71
[ 5111.944471] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 5180.278403] debugfs: Directory '15' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5180.405436] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 72 using xhci_hcd
[ 5180.533455] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5180.769486] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5180.877524] debugfs: Directory '16' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5181.005462] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 73 using xhci_hcd
[ 5181.133522] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5181.369528] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5181.477537] usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
[ 5181.793554] debugfs: Directory '17' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5182.129530] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 74 using xhci_hcd
[ 5182.129727] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5182.129772] debugfs: Directory '18' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5182.337754] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5182.337799] debugfs: Directory '19' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5182.545548] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 74, error -71
[ 5182.673566] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 75 using xhci_hcd
[ 5182.673759] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5182.673804] debugfs: Directory '21' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5182.881742] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5182.881776] debugfs: Directory '22' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5183.089595] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 75, error -71
[ 5183.089681] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 5210.936647] debugfs: Directory '23' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5211.063659] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 76 using xhci_hcd
[ 5211.191710] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5211.427717] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5211.535816] debugfs: Directory '24' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5211.663707] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 77 using xhci_hcd
[ 5211.791748] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5212.027766] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5212.135801] usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
[ 5212.451831] debugfs: Directory '25' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5212.787802] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 78 using xhci_hcd
[ 5212.788015] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5212.788072] debugfs: Directory '26' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5212.996028] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5212.996088] debugfs: Directory '27' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5213.203822] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 78, error -71
[ 5213.331841] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 79 using xhci_hcd
[ 5213.332052] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5213.332110] debugfs: Directory '29' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5213.540015] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5213.540060] debugfs: Directory '30' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5213.747864] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 79, error -71
[ 5213.747945] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 5274.737433] debugfs: Directory '31' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5274.864377] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 80 using xhci_hcd
[ 5274.992462] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5275.228460] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5275.336526] debugfs: Directory '32' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5275.464400] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 81 using xhci_hcd
[ 5275.592447] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5275.828466] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5275.936500] usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
[ 5276.252509] debugfs: Directory '33' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5276.588499] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 82 using xhci_hcd
[ 5276.588711] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5276.588769] debugfs: Directory '34' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5276.796702] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5276.796743] debugfs: Directory '35' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5277.004547] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 82, error -71
[ 5277.132541] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 83 using xhci_hcd
[ 5277.132752] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5277.132810] debugfs: Directory '37' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5277.340756] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5277.340815] debugfs: Directory '38' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5277.548546] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 83, error -71
[ 5277.548627] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 5585.585523] debugfs: Directory '39' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5585.712438] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 84 using xhci_hcd
[ 5585.840350] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5586.076403] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5586.184419] debugfs: Directory '40' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5586.316323] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 85 using xhci_hcd
[ 5586.444351] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5586.680392] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5586.788400] usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
[ 5587.104397] debugfs: Directory '41' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5587.440372] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 86 using xhci_hcd
[ 5587.440564] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5587.440622] debugfs: Directory '42' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5587.648606] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5587.648665] debugfs: Directory '43' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5587.856326] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 86, error -71
[ 5587.984366] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 87 using xhci_hcd
[ 5587.984557] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5587.984601] debugfs: Directory '45' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5588.192557] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5588.192603] debugfs: Directory '46' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5588.400364] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 87, error -71
[ 5588.400434] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 5683.789804] debugfs: Directory '47' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5683.916701] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 88 using xhci_hcd
[ 5684.044755] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5684.280760] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5684.388835] debugfs: Directory '48' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5684.516720] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 89 using xhci_hcd
[ 5684.644778] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5684.880768] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5684.988765] usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
[ 5685.304766] debugfs: Directory '49' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5685.640720] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 90 using xhci_hcd
[ 5685.640923] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5685.640967] debugfs: Directory '50' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5685.848908] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5685.848943] debugfs: Directory '51' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5686.056729] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 90, error -71
[ 5686.184716] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 91 using xhci_hcd
[ 5686.184912] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5686.184963] debugfs: Directory '53' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5686.392927] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5686.392988] debugfs: Directory '54' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5686.600722] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 91, error -71
[ 5686.600825] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 5729.402022] debugfs: Directory '55' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5729.528950] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 92 using xhci_hcd
[ 5729.656963] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5729.893004] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5730.001036] debugfs: Directory '56' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5730.128974] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 93 using xhci_hcd
[ 5730.257009] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5730.492941] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5730.600935] usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
[ 5730.916984] debugfs: Directory '57' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5731.252915] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 94 using xhci_hcd
[ 5731.253128] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5731.253172] debugfs: Directory '58' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5731.461022] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5731.461097] debugfs: Directory '59' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5731.668889] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 94, error -71
[ 5731.800954] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 95 using xhci_hcd
[ 5731.801069] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5731.801206] debugfs: Directory '61' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5732.009169] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5732.009215] debugfs: Directory '62' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5732.216969] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 95, error -71
[ 5732.217068] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 5811.370982] debugfs: Directory '63' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5811.497459] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 96 using xhci_hcd
[ 5811.625603] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5811.861605] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5811.969622] debugfs: Directory '64' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5812.097439] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 97 using xhci_hcd
[ 5812.229573] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5812.465561] usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 5812.573459] usb usb1-port6: attempt power cycle
[ 5812.893593] debugfs: Directory '02' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5813.233451] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 98 using xhci_hcd
[ 5813.233689] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5813.233843] debugfs: Directory '03' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5813.441678] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5813.441825] debugfs: Directory '04' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5813.649457] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 98, error -71
[ 5813.649640] debugfs: Directory '05' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5813.777458] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 99 using xhci_hcd
[ 5813.777706] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5813.777846] debugfs: Directory '06' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5813.985690] usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 5813.985835] debugfs: Directory '07' with parent 'devices' already present!
[ 5814.193454] usb 1-6: device not accepting address 99, error -71
[ 5814.193524] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
```

It only stops doing this when I unplug the charger. I plugged the Dell 45W charger in and notice no lag or message in `dmesg`. Is there something to do or just "get over it and live with your lag"?

Edit: After a search for "device descriptor read/64" it turns out the USB port tries first to provide power to my charger. Is there a way to the the USB port that my device is a charger and not some power hungry USB device?

Comment: Suggest : Connect your charger to a 230V→USB wall outlet. A computer usb port is not meant to feed a power supply. If really 60W : That's about 5V 12Amps !

Comment: Hi Knud, thanks for your answer but this is a real universal USB-C laptop charger meant to charge all kind of USB devices. So it ranges from 5V to 20V like all USB-C chagers are meant to work.